# possible to observe a property in another class with swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way, in swift 2.0 or later, to observe a property change in another class without invoking objective-c?

i have seen few examples online and all of them use objective-c APIs.

Comment: It's not possible to write an iOS app without invoking Objective-C APIs. Thus I wouldn't worry about avoiding those. That said, though, KVO, the technology you are after,  is only supported for objects that inherit from NSObject, so in this case using this API does impose some restrictions (You can't use KVO on Swift structs, for example, since they can't inherit from NSObject.)

Comment: I suppose you could use delegation, via a protocol, and `didSet` and/or `willSet` for the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way in Swift to remotely observe property changes without using Objective-C key-value observing.

KVO simply wraps property setters around code that notifies observers. It does it implicitly, though. So just make it explicit.

Comment: I know KVO isn't magic, and not objecting to it.  It does sometimes feel clunky and a bit overkill though.  I was more hoping that swift had a simpler, lighter-weight way to do the task.